# At he and or at his and?

Tags: grammar

The [headline](https://flipboard.com/topic/wedding/a-family-affair-for-boris-as-sister-rachel-arrives-at-he-and-carrie-s-wedding-ce/a-BzPiUvFlRzyH3JkVY3O1RQ%3Aa%3A2679765603-9d3bcef76f%2Fco.uk) reads:

> A family affair for Boris as sister Rachel arrives at he and Carrie's wedding celebration party.

Is the subjective 'he' after the proposition 'at' incorrect?

Comment: No, it isn't correct. It should be "his and Carrie's wedding celebration" or less clumsy as "their wedding celebration". To use 'he' a sentence might be "He and Carrie held a wedding celebration party."

Comment: Guess what Victor Meldrew would say if he read that! :)

Comment: I don't believe it

Comment: There is a weird superstition in English that, whenever a pronoun is yoked by ‘and’ with either a noun or another pronoun, it must be nominative (*he, I* etc.).  Calling this nonsense may be the sin of prescriptivism, but logic argues for using the same form as if the other partner (*Carrie's*) were not there.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Surely not _their_ in this sentence - it would sound as though he had married his sister!

Comment: @AntonSherwood I suspect it comes from the non-pronoun version being "Boris and Carrie's wedding" -- since "Boris" isn't a possessive, it may seem natural to replace it with a nominative pronoun.

Comment: @Barmar That would explain “he and Carrie's” but not “my sister and I's” (which I read recently).

Comment: May we not drop Carrie, then look again at 'he wedding'? Could that work? How?